# make bottom line view colourful when i am writing inside textfield in ios swift

Tags: swift, uiview, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I have to make bottomline view  colorful when i am trying to update my textfield. After leaving that box color of line should take default color.I tried this but not works for all fields.I have set  delegate of textfield also.

```
 func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    self.titleLine.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.386627968, blue: 0.209040308, alpha: 1)
}
```

[taskImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BK6Sw.png)

Comment: did  you set the delegate

Comment: Yes. I have added in view did load  //TextField Delegate
        tfTags.delegate = self
        tfCategories.delegate = self
        tfTitle.delegate = self

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another delegate method and set the tag:

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if textField.tag == 100 {
       self.titleLine.backgroundColor = // your default colour
    } 
}
```

It may helps to you.thank you.

Comment: Please press the up button of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [SkyFloatingLabelTextField](https://github.com/Skyscanner/SkyFloatingLabelTextField) library.it may helps you